# how to look what happend in the container in pod given this while loop?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

The pod yaml is this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: front
  name: front
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: front
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - while true; echo date; sleep 2; done #suspect the bug is i forgot to add "do" before echo
```

describing pod does not help much. Events section only shows just 'crashloopbackoff' or error.

HOw to see exactly the root cause error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to see the logs of the pod:

`kubectl logs front`

or

`kubectl logs -f front`

if you want to follow the logs as they appear

Comment: yes perfect, the error from "k logs front" is this "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")"

Comment: Great. Now if you fix that in your pod yaml and redeploy it, you can use the same command to get the logs, and add the `-f` if you want to see the logs as they come out.